# Как запустить файл .cpp в IDE VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компиляция, компилятор, visual-studio-2019

На курсах предоставили исходные файлы урока: 2 файла с расширением .cpp.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как эти файлы добавить в Visual Studio 2019 и скомпилировать для просмотра результатов в консоли?
До этого давали уже проекты, созданные в VS и я просто открывал файл проекта "*.sln" и уже внутри переключался между примерами демонстрации.

Answer (score 0):

У Вас есть такой способ достигнуть результата:

1. Создайте в VS новый проект с типом "Console C++ project" (простейший проект, который представляет из себя файл, в котором написана одна процедура, выводящая в консоль "Hello, world!")
2. Теперь у вас есть проект, который открывается в VS. Но там нет того материала, который Вам дали на занятиях.
3. Замените содержимое единственного *.cpp файла в проекте на содержимое того файла, который Вам дали на занятиях. Проверьте, что результат компилируется и запускается.
4. По Вашему вопросу непонятно, 2 файла которые Вам дали - это две части одного проекта, или это два разных задания? Если это две части одного задания - Вы можете просто добавить в проект еще один *.cpp файл, или поступить даже проще - записать содержимое обеих файлов в один.

Comment: Это 2 разных проекта. Правильно я понимаю. Для добавления второго мне уже в существующем консольном проекте нужно в менеджере добавить ещё один проект. В результате у меня появиться второй пустой проект с выводом фразы "Hello, world!". И уже аналогично нужно заменить текст файла. Верно?